# Форма обратной связи не отправляет информацию на почту

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, form

Здравствуйте, есть форма обратной связи, но данные почему-то не отправляются на почту, консоль ошибки не выдает, помогите разобраться в чем проблема

**HTML**

```
<form>

    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
    <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="Site Name">
    <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="147qq147@i.ua">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Form Subject">
    <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

    <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="You name..." required><br>
    <input type="text" name="E-mail" placeholder="You E-mail..." required><br>
    <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="You phone..."><br>
    <button>Send</button>

</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //E-mail Ajax Send
    $("form").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Thank you!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });    
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

Comment: Не только в консоль смотрите, но и в лог ошибок на сервере.

Comment: Так а как вы пытаетесь принять данные из скрытых инпутов ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверь работает ли функция mail(). Если нет настрой sendmail или используй библиотеку, например https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

Уже решил проблему. Дело было даже не в скриптах, просто хостинг, на котором я тестил все это отключил для бесплатных аккаунтов функцию php mail(). Всем спасибо, кто пытался помочь